# How to disable swiping and enable it again?

Tags: javascript

I have code where 4 div elements act as pages and swiping on them gets you to the next/previous page.

```
function handleSwiping(allPagesArray){

    for(i=0; i<pageCount; i++){
        attachEvents(i);
    }

    function attachEvents(idx){
        var page = allPagesArray[idx];
        if(isVertical){
            te(page).on('swipeup', function (e) {
                gotoNextPage(idx);
            });
            te(page).on('swipedown', function (e) {
                gotoPrevPage(idx);
            });         
        } else {
            te(page).on('swipeleft', function (e) {
                gotoNextPage(idx);
            });
            te(page).on('swiperight', function (e) {
                gotoPrevPage(idx);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The `gotoNextPage` and `gotoPrevPage` functions have keyframe animations in them. What I need to achieve is that before the animation starts, I want to unbind these swipe events and bind them again after the animation ends. This is needed in case the user swipes again before the 'go to next page' animation is complete.

I need the solution in pure javascript. Jquery or any other framework won't do.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a global variable (or in an object somewhere), `isSwiping`.

```
 te(page).on('swipeup', function (e) {
    if(!isSwiping) {
       isSwiping = true; 
       gotoNextPage(idx);
    }
 });
```

Then set `isSwiping` to `false` when the animation ends

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'll try this and let you know how it went in a little while.

Comment: Remember to define `isSwiping` in an upper scope (global, or anywhere else), with `var isSwiping = false;`, otherwise `isSwiping` will be local to your function and will never be `true` on function start

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks for the simple, elegant solution.